# grunt-usemin : removing attributes from stylesheet

Tags: angularjs, grunt-usemin

I use following code :

`<!-- build:css css/base-style.css --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/base-style.css" ng-if="someCondition"> 
<!-- endbuild -->`

This block of code is replaced by

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base-style.css">`

is there any way to keep ng-if in output?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, try this it may help you until someone find a proper solution:

```
$("link:eq(0)").attr('ng-if', "someCondition")
```